# My compile error message : test.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `__sync_lock_test_and_set_1'

Tags: mips, cross-compiling

I want compile to mips

My test code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char a;

    a = 10;

    __sync_lock_test_and_set(&a, 1);
    __sync_lock_release(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

compile error message here

```
/tmp/ccs0M6bI.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `__sync_lock_test_and_set_1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My mips gcc compiler version is 4.3

(This problem is compiler version 4.7 is ok, but i'm can't use other version )

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Your error message is an error from the linker, not from the compiler. That test code won't compile because of the invalid `#include` directive. You are either providing wrong code example or wrong error message.

Comment: ok, so... how can i not change "gnu-ld" version , solve this issue?

Comment: Built-ins `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release` are probably available since gcc 4.4.

Comment: thanks, i'll try gcc 4.4